# XML transform with XSLT 1

Tags: xml, xslt

today im really struggling with XSLT, it has been a long time that i  had to use it. I have to edit some
xml  and i can't use XSLT 2.0. So i have to use 1.0. The xml im struugling with is (basic example) :

I tried making an template for the 2 nodes, and then 'call' that template to create a new node with the desired values but that didnt work either , im missing something if someone can point me into the right direction.

```html
<messagemap>
    <author>
        <au_id>274-80-9391</au_id>
        <au_lname>Straight</au_lname>
        <au_fname>Dean</au_fname>
        <phone>415 834-2919</phone>
        <address>5420 College Av.</address>
        <city>Oakland</city>
        <state>CA</state>
        <zip>94609</zip>
        <contract>1</contract>
    </author>
</messagemap>
```

XM:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <!--Identity Transform.-->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
   
    <xsl:template match="au_fname | au_lname">
        <company>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </company>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What i get as a result:

```html
<messagemap>
    <author>
        <au_id>274-80-9391</au_id>
        <company>Straight</company>
        <company>Dean</company>
        <phone>415 834-2919</phone>
        <address>5420 College Av.</address>
        <city>Oakland</city>
        <state>CA</state>
        <zip>94609</zip>
        <contract>1</contract>
    </author>
</messagemap>
```

What i need is:

```html
<messagemap>
    <author>
        <au_id>274-80-9391</au_id>
        <company>Dean Straight</company>
        <phone>415 834-2919</phone>
        <address>5420 College Av.</address>
        <city>Oakland</city>
        <state>CA</state>
        <zip>94609</zip>
        <contract>1</contract>
    </author>
</messagemap>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try matching `au_fname` and building `company`. You could then strip `au_lname`.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity Transform.-->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="au_fname">
        <company>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat(.,' ',../au_lname))"/>
        </company>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="au_lname"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What kind of witchcraftis this! Really, was it really that simple. Anyway thanks. I only have a question about the concat does the first '.,' equals au_fname then? The rest is very clear.

Comment: @JonathanRomer - You're very welcome. Yes the `.` is the current context which is `au_fname`. Also, the `normalize-space()` was added to strip the trailing space that would be added by the `concat()` if `../au_lname` didn't exist.

Comment: You are providing for the case where au_lname is missing, but disregard the possibility of au_fname not existing (as a node, not as a value).